# How to fix my jquery ajax login form that keeps redirecting to the action page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, authentication

I hope someone can help me understand what I am doing wrong.I am trying to login using a simple jquery form. When I click submit, the form redirects to the action page

I have tried looking for simple jquery templates but I always get redirected to the action page.
I used event.preventDefault() but it does not help

```
//HTML

 <div id ="login" class="container">
        <div class="md-5" id="loginContainer" style="margin-top:100px;content-alignment:center;">
          <form id="loginForm" class="form" action="mylogin.php" method="post" style="background: lightskyblue;margin: 5%;border: 2px;border-style: ridge;padding: 10%;">
            <label for="userName" >User Name</label>
            <input id="userName" type="text" name="userName" required=""><br><br>
            <label for="passWord">Password</label>
            <input id="passWord" type="password" name="passWord" required=""></br>
            <input type="submit" id="loginSubmit" value="Login">
          </form>
        <div id="upload-progress"><div class="progress-bar"></div></div> <!-- Progress bar added -->
        </div>

//script

$("#loginForm").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
    var userName=document.getElementById('userName');
    var password=document.getElementById('passWord');
    var form_data = {myformdatawithusernameandpassword}
}

    $.ajax({
        url : "mylogin.php",
        type: "post",
        data : form_data,
        contentType: false,
        processData:false,
        xhr: function(){
        //upload Progress
        var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if (xhr.upload) {
            xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
                var percent = 0;
                var position = event.loaded || event.position;
                var total = event.total;
                if (event.lengthComputable) {
                    percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
                }
                //update progressbar
                $("#upload-progress .progress-bar").css("width", + percent +"%");
            }, true);
        }
        return xhr;
    }
    }).done(function(response){ //
        $("#mainDashboard").html(response);
    });
});
```

I should get the response without redirecting or even refreshing the page

Answer (score 0):

Remove action of the form and also, change `<input type="submit
'>` to simple button, because submit type submits form and performs action specified in form tag.

Comment: Thank you.
I tried it and got the same. Basically, the login form is just for me to establish an API connection. and clicking login should return meta data including bearer token from the API server if the user is authenticated

Answer (score 0):

Adapt your submit callback to a [click handler](https://api.jquery.com/click/) for the button.

Your event.preventDefault() should then successfully prevent the form action.